# can a typeScript method know its name ( like PHP's __FUNCTION__ magic constant? )?

Tags: angular, typescript

Are there magic constants in Angular 2, TypeScript?

Here is what I would wish to exist:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log (__CURRENT_METHOD_NAME__ + has started running'); 
  // outputs ngOnInit has started running. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Are there magic constants in Angular 2, TypeScript?

None for current method name.

## More

Unreliably you can use err.stack https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack , but I wouldn't.